# Python, вывод кодированного текста в конслось

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется Python 3.7.2
Имеется txt файл в кодировке cp1251, в нём текст на русском.
Пытаюсь его вывести в консоль, а она мне выдает: codecs.StreamReaderWriter object at 0x0135adb0
Так вот, как сделать чтобы выводился текст?
Код:
import codecs
with codecs.open(r"D:\pythonw\qwer1.txt", "r", encoding="cp1251") as line:
    print(line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[codecs.open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) возвращает не строку, а хэндлер открытого файла, из которого можно строки считывать:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open(r"D:\pythonw\qwer1.txt", "r", encoding="cp1251") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        print(line)
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло, а можно ссылку, где про это почитать в документации.

Comment: В ответе есть ссылка. И [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) ещё можно.

Comment: не обратил внимания, спасибо еще раз)